# How to convert Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Please help me convert Objective-C to Swift, my first exposure coding.
I had tried to convert, but I can't solve it.

```
 NSString* deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

 NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://emlscer.no-ip.info:8080/sample/iAppList.php?add=%@",  deviceTokenString];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

}

Swift:

```
var deviceTokenString: String = deviceToken.description.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

var link: String = "http://emlscer.no-ip.info:8080/sample/iAppList.php?add=\(deviceTokenString)"

if let linkWithPercentEscape = link.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
if let url = NSURL(string: linkWithPercentEscape)  {
var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

  }
}
```

Comment: Take it one line at a time, to see exactly where you come unstuck. Also, take a particular look at the new guard let syntax. Your Swift is not dreadful, though you don't need to explicitly define the type in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more correct than iPrabu's answer, which is incomplete.

```
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.debugDescription.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

let link = "http://emlscer.no-ip.info:8080/sample/iAppList.php?add=\(deviceTokenString)"

if let
    escapedString = link.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    url = NSURL(string: escapedString)
{
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    do {
        try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
    } catch {
        // Handle your error
    }
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind this code will stop working sometime. sendSynchronousRequest is deprecated, as is stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding. Using a debugDescription is probably a bad idea, and the chained stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString isn't great either. Basically, you're starting with some fairly rubbish code. I've simply translated it, but you should really try to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to learn swift using the swift programming book provided by apple.

[Start from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309)

Anyhow posting the swift replacement here

```
var deviceTokenString = deviceToken.debugDescription.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")

var link = "http://emlscer.no-ip.info:8080/sample/iAppList.php?add=\(deviceTokenString)"

var url = NSURL(string: link)

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
```